# pygame.error: unable to create gl context

Tags: python, opengl

I am trying to follow some OpenGL tutorials and I'm having this error : `pygame.error: unable to create gl context`.
The error occurs in the function :

```
pygame.display.set_mode([800,600],OPENGL|DOUBLEBUF)
```

I am using PyopenGL3.1 with Pygame and PyQt4. I was wondering if it is a hardware related problem (my GPU is HD7600M).

Comment: What is `screen_size`?

Comment: Just a variable containing the screen size. I've editted it

Answer (score -1):

i get this if im multi-threading pygame. If your multi-threading make sure the pygame is not starting in a new thread.

Comment: This helped me but for a slightly different error. I was getting "pygame.error: Unable to make EGL context current (call to eglMakeCurrent failed, reporting an error of EGL_BAD_ACCESS)" when calling "pygame.display.flip()" from a newly spawned thread. When I moved the call to flip() to the main executing thread the above error went away.

Answer (score -2):

Well I faced this problem when starting openGL on a virtual machine (windows xp).

This problem occurs if your GPU is unable to create the GL context.
If you have a second GPU (NVIDIA, RADEON), make it the default GPU for python.
That solved the problem for me.

Have a nice day

Comment: Well, how do you do that...?

Comment: the most useless answer so far, give an example!